# Issue installing MP4Box: "image not found Abort trap: 6"

Tags: macos, installation, terminal, mp4box

I installed GPAC on a mac running OSX 10.13, and then followed a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R0STwCVDizE) to install MP4box by doing:

```
 sudo cp /Applications/GPAC.app/Contents/MacOS/MP4Box /usr/local/bin
 sudo cp -R /Applications/GPAC.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/* /usr/local/bin
 MP4Box
```

But in response I got:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/lib/libgpac.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/MP4Box
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

I checked and libgpac.dylib is definitely in bin, so what happened? What do I do? Any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GPAC maintainer here.

On OS X you need to copy the lib in the lib folder, not the bin one: `sudo cp -R /Applications/GPAC.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/* /usr/local/lib`

By the way I urge you to follow the [official doc](https://github.com/gpac/gpac/wiki/GPAC-Build-Guide-for-OSX).